# show input user string in a asp.net textbox

Tags: string, textbox, execute

i have a aspx page and there is a form in it, i get the user input and then in a script i add those inputs in a sentence and put it in a string, now i want to show the final string in a textbox or any same asp container which i can call it from codebehind.

this is part of my from and scripts code snippet

FORM

```
<form method="get" action="Default.aspx">
Name: <input type="text" name="uname"/><br/>
Distributaion List: <input type="text" name="dname"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="add" />
</form>
```

SCRIPT (which gets the user input and add some text and put it into a string which is "Scode"

```
<%
string uname, dname, scode;
uname = Request.QueryString["uname"];
dname = Request.QueryString["dname"];
Response.Write( "<br/>"+"Okay! " + uname + " is adding to " + dname + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
scode = ("CUSTOM TEXT1" + dname + "CUSTOM TEXT2" + uname + "CUSTOM TEXT3" + "<br/>");
Response.Write("if it is ok, just need to click on execute button" + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
Response.Write(scode);
%>
```

TEXT BOX( which i execute the content of this textbox later )

```
            <asp:Button ID="ExecuteCode" runat="server" Text="Execute" Width="200" onclick="ExecuteCode_Click" />
```

as you can see in script part, i want to show the content of the Response.Write(scode); in to the text box

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it was really easy, since i was new to it i was struggling with it.
the only thing that should be done is storing the string into the desired text box, just like below

```
textbox.Text = scode;
```